# Cannot push object to array in js

Tags: javascript

I attempt to push something to my array. But when i use console.log it return an empty array. As a beginner, I am wondering if I did anything wrong?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1')
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

let particlesArray

class Particles {
  constructor(x, y, directionX, directionY) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.directionX = directionX
    this.directionY = directionY
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle = "#c1dfdc"
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.fill()
  }

}

particlesArray = []

//calculate how many particles should render
numberOfParticles = window.innerHeight * window.innerWidth / 9000

function generateParticlesArray() {
  for (let i; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
    let x = Math.random()
    let y = Math.random()
    let directionX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8
    let directionY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8
    particlesArray.push(new Particles(x, y, directionX, directionY))
  }
  console.log(particlesArray)
}

generateParticlesArray()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: What is the value of `numberOfParticles = window.innerHeight * window.innerWidth / 9000` if you log it on the line right after?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(particlesArray);`

Comment: @zr0gravity7 it return 57

Comment: @ControlAltDel just got a blank bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is forgetting to initialize your iterator variable `i` in the begin part of your `for` loop statement:

```
    for (let i; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
        ...
```

Should instead be:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) { // notice we declare and initialize i with let i = 0;
        ...
```

You can indeed see that the below for loop below will not iterate at all:

```js
const x = 10;

for (let i; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
console.log("done");
```

This is because `i` implicitly takes on the value of `undefined` if it is declared but not initialized. Numerical comparisons with `undefined` cause it to get converted to `NaN`, a special numeric value which returns false for all comparisons. See https://javascript.info/comparison#an-incomparable-undefined

Comment: this should have been a comment and a vote to close as typo. Not much added value here

Answer (score 0):

You missed a 0 in `let i=0;`

Also you have too many assignments. Just have one and DRY: Don't repeat yourself:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  iW = window.innerWidth,
  iH = window.innerHeight,
  numberOfParticles = parseInt(iH * iW / 9000);  //calculate how many particles should render

canvas.width = iW; canvas.height = iH;
ctx.fillStyle = "grey"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

class Particles {
  constructor(x, y, directionX, directionY) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.directionX = directionX; this.directionY = directionY;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#c1dfdc";
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

const generateParticlesArray = numberOfParticles => Array
  .from({ length: numberOfParticles })
  .map((_, i) => new Particles(Math.random(), Math.random(), (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8, (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8))

let particlesArray = generateParticlesArray(numberOfParticles)
particlesArray.forEach(particle => particle.draw())
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```